# Object becomes undefined in node.js simple server

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

Alright, so when I run this server:

```
var net = require('net');

var server = net.createServer(function (data) {
    console.log("Hello " + data.name);
});

server.listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');
```

and then browse this page on chrome (from a file, not a domain):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var data = new function(){
                this.name = "John";
            };

            $.post('http://127.0.0.1:1337/', data);
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    </body>
</html>
```

I get the following output on my server:

```
Hello undefinied
```

My question is, why does my data object's name become undefined when I send it to the server?

---

Edit: So I changed my server to this:

```
var http = require('http');

var server = http.createServer(function (data) {
    console.log("Hello " + data.name);
});

server.listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');
```

and changed my client's script to this:

```
var data = {
                name: "John"
            };
            $.post('http://127.0.0.1:1337/', data);
```

But I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: Are you even following the given examples? Quentin gave example: [Scroll to bottom and you will see a sample HTTP server](http://nodejs.org/)

Comment: What makes you think the server connection callback will automatically give you the object you created and sent on the client?

Comment: @Mustafa What I want is to send a object to the server, and have the server print out a value of the object (in this case the name). I don't want to make text say hello world.

Comment: Are you aware of HTTP protocol? If you do, Just read the [HTTP docs of NodeJS](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html)

Comment: If you're looking for magic, you won't find it. You need to study the API and write the appropriate code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`net.connection` creates a plain TCP socket, not an HTTP server.

You want `http.createServer` instead, and the function it accepts as its argument doesn't get a simple object containing just the submitted data. You need to read the manual for the `http` module and see how to process a request object.

There is an example [on the node.js homepage](http://nodejs.org/) (just scroll down).

See also the API docs for [request events](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_event_request) and [node.js Extracting POST data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4295782/node-js-extracting-post-data).

Comment: `data` *is* a simple object. The anonymous function is being invoked as a constructor with `new`.

Comment: @thesystem — Which makes it an instance of the anonymous constructor function, not a simple object.

Comment: Alright, I made the changes (as reflected in my edit), but I'm getting the same error.

Comment: @thesystem — Although, having tested it, it looks like jQuery can cope with that, so I've deleted the first portion of the answer as it was a red herring. (It is decidedly atypical code though)

Comment: @CyanPrime — All you've done is change to using `http` instead of `net`. That's the first step. Read the rest of the answer.